# Paramiko SFTP FILE UPLOAD FILE NOT FOUND

Tags: python-3.x

I am struggling with this one and I have come across a similar problem  but I could not understand it.  The problem seems to be with the paramiko sftp.put(**localpath**). I know I am doing it wrong can't figure out how to fix it.  Please note I have heavily modified the original code.  As I said earlier, I came across a similar problem but I do not understand the resolution.

```
import paramiko

pk = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key(private_key_file)
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect("hostname", username = "test", password = "password", pkey = 
pk)
sftp = ssh.open_sftp()

#some files. previous_week from week number generator
PC_Rank = 'some_file_WK%s.csv' %previous_week
PC_SA = 'WK%s_some_other_file.csv' %previous_week
#Python list
Files = [PC_Rank, PC_SA]
#windows server file location
local_path = "\\10.245.102.21\Files\#GIS Files\#csv_output\delete" 
#Defining remote directory
remote_path = "Images/Staging/coverage_checker"
sftp.chdir(remote_path)

for filename in Files:
    sftp.put(local_path, filename)
```

Comment: I forgot to add that, it runs but it does not upload any files.  The files cannot be found.

Comment: Try adding `confirm=True` to the `sftp.put()` call? That is supposed to verify the file was uploaded successfully.